how to change titles in UploadThing
I'm using the library UploadThing. And I want to change these names to my own:

This is my code
"use client";

import toast from "react-hot-toast";

import { UploadDropzone } from "@/lib/uploadthing";
import { ourFileRouter } from "@/app/api/uploadthing/core";

interface FileUploadProps {
  onChange: (url?: string) => void;
  endpoint: keyof typeof ourFileRouter;

};

export const FileUpload = ({
  onChange,
  endpoint,
}: FileUploadProps) => {
  return (
    <UploadDropzone
      endpoint={endpoint}
      onClientUploadComplete={(res) => {
        onChange(res?.[0].url);
      }}
      onUploadError={(error: Error) => {
        toast.error(`${error?.message}`);
      }}
    />
  )
}

I would like to get this result. I was able to do this through the element code:


Since the theming documentation for the UploadThing library doesn't cover text adjustments directly, you might need to use a combination of custom CSS and possibly JavaScript to change the text elements like button labels, which are not explicitly covered by the theming options in https://docs.uploadthing.com/theming.
If the text you want to change (like button labels or tooltips) is embedded within the JavaScript component and not configurable via props, you might need to use JavaScript to dynamically change these texts after the component has rendered.
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import toast from "react-hot-toast";
import { UploadDropzone } from "@/lib/uploadthing";
import { ourFileRouter } from "@/app/api/uploadthing/core";

interface FileUploadProps {
  onChange: (url?: string) => void;
  endpoint: keyof typeof ourFileRouter;
};

export const FileUpload = ({ onChange, endpoint }: FileUploadProps) => {
  const dropzoneRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const button = dropzoneRef.current?.querySelector('button');
    if (button) {
      button.textContent = 'Custom Upload Text'; // Change the button text dynamically
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <UploadDropzone
      ref={dropzoneRef}
      endpoint={endpoint}
      onClientUploadComplete={(res) => onChange(res?.[0].url)}
      onUploadError={(error: Error) => toast.error(`${error?.message}`)}
    />
  );
};

Update according to my latest comment:
Observer code
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import toast from "react-hot-toast";
import { UploadDropzone } from "@/lib/uploadthing";
import { ourFileRouter } from "@/app/api/uploadthing/core";

interface FileUploadProps {
  onChange: (url?: string) => void;
  endpoint: keyof typeof ourFileRouter;
};

export const FileUpload = ({ onChange, endpoint }: FileUploadProps) => {
  const dropzoneRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      const button = dropzoneRef.current?.querySelector('button');
      if (button && button.textContent !== 'Custom Upload Text') {
        button.textContent = 'Custom Upload Text';
      }
    }, 100); // Check every 100 ms

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return (
    <UploadDropzone
      ref={dropzoneRef}
      endpoint={endpoint}
      onClientUploadComplete={(res) => onChange(res?.[0].url)}
      onUploadError={(error: Error) => toast.error(`${error?.message}`)}
    />
  );
};

setInterval code
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import toast from "react-hot-toast";
import { UploadDropzone } from "@/lib/uploadthing";
import { ourFileRouter } from "@/app/api/uploadthing/core";

interface FileUploadProps {
  onChange: (url?: string) => void;
  endpoint: keyof typeof ourFileRouter;
};

export const FileUpload = ({ onChange, endpoint }: FileUploadProps) => {
  const dropzoneRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      const button = dropzoneRef.current?.querySelector('button');
      if (button && button.textContent !== 'Custom Upload Text') {
        button.textContent = 'Custom Upload Text';
      }
    }, 100); // Check every 100 ms

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return (
    <UploadDropzone
      ref={dropzoneRef}
      endpoint={endpoint}
      onClientUploadComplete={(res) => onChange(res?.[0].url)}
      onUploadError={(error: Error) => toast.error(`${error?.message}`)}
    />
  );
};


Thank you! The solution is interesting, but it did not help solve the problem. The required text appears for a millisecond - then everything returns as it was? Is there really no way to permanently replace the text in a button and in the "label"?

The text seems to be dynamically reset by the library's JavaScript component after our changes. Seems the component re-renders or updates its state, which could overwrite our DOM changes. Contact the library developers and ask/request a feature. You could also use a MutationObserver, which is an API in JavaScript that allows you to watch DOM changes, used to detect when the text is reset and to apply your custom text again. You could also set up an interval to periodically check and update the button text using setInterval. I made updates to my post.

<UploadthingButton
        onClientUploadComplete={onClientUploadComplete}
        onUploadError={onUploadError}
        endpoint={endpoint}
        config={{ mode }}
        content={{
            button: ({ ready, isUploading }) => {
                if (!ready) return "Preparando...";
                if (isUploading) return "Enviando...";
                return "Enviar arquivo";
            },
            allowedContent: ({ ready, fileTypes, isUploading }) => {
                if (!ready) return "Verificando tipos de arquivo permitidos...";
                if (isUploading) return "Enviando arquivo...";
                return `Tipos de arquivo permitidos: ${fileTypes.join(", ")}`;
            },
        }}
    />


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
